# How do I test a JQuery Plugin with Jasmine?

Tags: jquery, jasmine

What is the best way to unit test JQuery code with Jasmine?

I have this simple jQuery test app:

```
<div id='log'>log goes here</div>
<button id='btnClearLog'>Clear log</button>
<button id='btnAddLog'>Add log</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#log').empty(); 

    $('#btnClearLog').click(function () {
        $('#log').empty();  
    }); 

    $('#btnAddLog').click(function() {
        $('#log').append("<br />something");    
    }); 
});
</script>
```

This works as expected - div#log is empty when document loads, add to #log and clear #log when clicked.

But I don't think it is possible to unit test this since the JQuery code is inside the HTML page.

So, I have re-written it like this:

```
<div id='log'>log goes here</div>
<button id='btnClearLog'>Clear log</button>
<button id='btnAddLog'>Add log</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#log').tester(); 

});
</script>
```

and have externalised the JQuery code into a separate file - like so - based on generated jQuery plugin code from http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/

```
(function($){

    $.Tester = function(el){

    var base = this;

            base.init = function(){

        $('#log').empty();

        $('#btnClearLog').click(function() {
            base.clear();
        });

        $('#btnAddLog').click(function() {
            base.add();
        });
            };

    base.clear = function(){
        $('#log').empty();
            };

    base.add = function(){
        $('#log').append("<br />something"); 
            };

            base.init();
    };

    $.fn.tester = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            (new $.Tester(this));
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

This also works as expected.

However, my attempt at a Jasmine script does not work.

```
describe('tester', function() { 

    it('log should be empty', function() { 
        var log = "<div id='log'>log</div>";
        var result = $(log).tester();
        expect(result).toBeEmpty();
    }

});
```

I've tried various permutations of the above - all fail with:

```
"Expected '<div id="log">log</div>' to be empty"
```

Is it possible to test a plugin written in this way?

Is it better to write the code in another way to make it more testable?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems here. First you mix testing your code with testing functionality of query code. So `expect(result).toBeEmpty();` will test that this  `$('#log').empty()` piece of code was called, which is right to test, but it also test that the element is empty, which is not your job here.

Second, you create new instances in your code you wanna test, what makes it hard to test, cause you have deal with `$`. So after all it would be better only to test your `Tester()` function and insert all elements right to it:

```
(function($){

    $.Tester = function(el, log, btnClearLog, btnAddLog){

    var base = this;

            base.init = function(){

        log.empty();

        btnClearLog.click(function() {
            base.clear();
        });

        btnAddLog.click(function() {
            base.add();
        });
            };

    base.clear = function(){
        log.empty();
            };

    base.add = function(){
        log.append("<br />something"); 
            };

            base.init();
    };

    $.fn.tester = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            (new $.Tester(this, $('#log'), $('#btnClearLog'), $('#btnAddLog')));
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Doing it so you can test only your Tester, passing in some mocks instead of real DOM elements. Take a look at [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) on how to create and use mocks. As we are in JavaScript world you can also mock JQuery away, simply dont insert jquery into your test side but displaces it by a mock.